# Does a compact folding luggage cart used to move around a carry-on bag and personal item count as an extra carry-on bag or extra personal item?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

Does a compact folding luggage cart used to move around a carry-on bag or personal item count as an extra carry-on bag or extra personal item? Or does it count as part of the carry-on bag or personal item it is carrying, and subsequently doesn't incur any additional fee?

Comment: If it were to count as part of the carry-on bag, the two combined would need to fall within the permitted sizes and weight limits. This article seems to indicate that these type of luggage carts can be used as part of carry-on https://www.knaviation.net/best-luggage-carts

Comment: Ideally, pick a luggage cart that, when folded, can go in your carry-on bag.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the airline for example Xiamen Air in China do not count foldable luggage carts as extra carry on and happily lets it come in board without issues.

However I tried the same on Air China and had to check it.

So best check the rules on the airline in question